# Keyboard combination detection in Psychtoolbox-3

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I want my experiment to have a key-combination to serve as an indicator to elicit an initiated exit from the experiment.

Now I have this code, which detects a single key press:

```
while(1)
     [keyIsDown,~,keyCode]=KbCheck;
     if keyIsDown
          if keyCode(SOME_KEY)
                 exitExperiment();
          end
          break;
     end
end
```

I wish that `SOME_KEY` would refer to a key combination, like `ctrl+r` or `shift+ESC`. Any other solution that will allow to refer to a combination of key presses will surely help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for a combination of keys, by checking that `all` of the appropriate key codes in the keyCode logical array are true. Here is an example that requires pressing the left control key and the r key at the same time:

```
% setup
KbName('UnifyKeyNames');
needed_key_names = {'LeftControl', 'r'};
needed_key_codes = KbName(needed_key_names);

while(1)
     [keyIsDown,~,keyCode]=KbCheck();
     if keyIsDown
          if all(keyCode(needed_key_codes))
             break;
          end
     end
end
```